# About finite dimensionality of Chow groups of zero cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, complex-geometry, schemes, chow-groups

Let $S$  be a connected smooth complex projective surface.

Let $Sym^{d}(S)$, $d\in \mathbb{Z}^+_0$,  be the $d$-th symmetric product of $S$ parametrizing $0$-cycles  of degree $d$.

Let $Sym^{d,d}(S)=Sym^{d}(S)\times Sym^{d}(S)$.

Let  $\theta^S_d: Sym^{d,d}(S) \rightarrow CH_0(S)_{\deg=0}$ the natural map defined by $(Z_1,Z_2) \mapsto  [Z_1-Z_2]$. Here $[Z_1-Z_2]$ is the class of $Z_1-Z_2$ modulo rational equivalence.

By  mumford Lemma  we know that the fibers of $\theta^S_d$ are countable union of closed algebraic subsets of $Sym^{d,d}(S)$.

On the other hand, we know  that the  dimension of the  imagen of $\theta^S_d$ is defined  as follows:
\begin{equation*}
    \dim(im(\theta^S_d))= \dim(Sym^{d,d}(S))- r_d= 2(2)d-r_d,
\end{equation*}
where $r_d$ is the dimension of the general fiber.

We say that $CH_0(X)_{\deg=0}$ is infinite dimensional if
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{d\rightarrow \infty}\dim im(\theta^X_d)=\infty,
\end{equation*}
and finite dimensional  otherwise.

If  I prove that the general fiber  is uncountable. Can  I say  that the above limit  is finite?